# CKeditor to search images on PC instead of server

Tags: 7, nodes, wysiwyg, media

I have added the CK editor WYSIWYG to my website.

However I want user to browse their own local PC directory when uploading images and not the server. The default Image module from drupal core does this fine how can I do this with CKeditor?

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the "upload" tab in your screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do this:

1. Install [IMCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdjU0.jpg)
2. Go to Configuration > Content authoring > CKEditor. Click **edit** for the **Full** profile
3. Expand the **File browser** fieldset. Select **IMCE** in the dropdown menu under **File browser type.** Save.

Then, when you click the **Browser Server** button, you will see the following window. Notice the Upload button. Clicking it will allow the user to select a file from their computer.
[image]

Comment: I have decided to use your answer as I cannot use CKeditor uploader as It's a paid service... however I am not getting anything in the navigational bar! http://i.imgur.com/YCE4FFH.png

Comment: There may be many reasons why this is happening. Check this installation tutorial http://easydrupalsolutions.blogspot.in/2014/09/blog-post_2.html. Also check that your public file folder has public write permission in your server. Also be sure to select "Full HTML" (rather than "Filtered HTML") in the text box you are trying to edit. These are blind guesses - you'll need to do your own debugging. IMCE and CKEditor can be finicky. ALSO remember to clear your cache and reload pages every time whenever you do tests.

Comment: I saw you asked this question in a different thread - good idea. Since you found my answer useful, can you vote it up or mark it as correct?

Comment: So sad to read the 1st comment here, but then such users don't seem to know (or care?) about what's written in [someone answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) ...

Answer (score 0):

As @PatrickRyan suggested to add images to the server from your local PC you will have to click on 'upload'

[image]